# Python intermittently throws "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'" on the same dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary like so:

```
mail = {
   'data': { 'from': {'text': '123@example.com'}}
    # some other entries...
}
```

I'm trying to copy `from` value using following code:

```
data = mail.get('data')
new_dict['parse']['from'] = data.get('from').get('text')
```

The second line throws the exception:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

The strange thing is, this only happens sometimes. If I add a print statement just before the second line like:

```
data = mail.get('data')
print(type(data.get('from')))
new_dict['parse']['from'] = data.get('from').get('text')
```

The error disappears and I get `<class 'dict'>` as expected. If I remove the print statement, it works sometimes and other times it throws the error. Nothing else changes in the code or data. The reason I'm using `get()` is to retrieve value safely in case the key is missing.

Comment: Using `get` is not safer than using bracket notation in this case beacuse you are not specifying a default value to use instead.

Comment: this code with this example `mail` object does not fail so we cannot help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the call `data.get('from').get('text')`, if `data` does not contain the key `'from'`, it will return `None`. `None.get('text')` raises then the exception you see, because a `None` object has no `get` method (of course).

The way around this is to pass in a better default-object than `None` (the default default-object), which has the `get` method. That would be an empty dictionary, `{}`:

```
data = mail.get('data')
new_dict['parse']['from'] = data.get('from', {}).get('text')
```

Comment: But the key `from` is there... As I mentioned, the dictionary you see in `mail` is actually what I'm passing. Thanks for the suggested improvement though.

Comment: @swdon Apparently it sometimes isn't and you have not been lucky enough to catch one of those instances when you inserted the `print` statement.

Comment: Thank you! Since this change, I'm not getting the error anymore.

Comment: @swdon "But the key from is there" => if Python tells you it's not then it's not, period.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, there's no such a thing. The point of the question was to understand why a program was behaving in an unspecified way under fully specified conditions. If Python is gospel to you, that's fine. Some of us are interested in knowing more than that.

Comment: @swdon What I meant is that your assumption about "fully specified conditions" is obviously wrong - you have this error because your dict does NOT have this key (sometimes at least), else it wouldn't produce this error. When my compiler or interpreter tells me something is not what I expect it to be, I first question my expectations. Note that this is nowhere specific to Python FWIW.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers It would be very interesting if you can explain why the interpreter may be failing to read hard-coded values in a dict *sometimes*. But I understand your point.

Comment: @swdon Without seeing that interpreter of yours, we cannot know. All we know is that the object returned by `mail.get('data')` is sometimes a dictionary (because it has the `get` method, otherwise you would have to do `mail.get('data', {})`) that does not have the key `'from'`. It is highly unlikely (as in, almost ridiculously unlikely) that Python messes up reading the memory correctly and much more likely that the problem is further up the pipe in whatever produces the `mail` dictionary.

Comment: @swdon please download this script and run it from your command line. When it will reproduce your error, come back and report.... I hope you're not in a hurry <g>
 https://gist.github.com/BrunoDesthuilliers/72e4c840fddbbd4f0122cb95bb82765c

Comment: @Graipher another possible cause would be another part of the code deleting the key from the dict. Quite a few people blindly assume that assignment or argument passing create copies and post here wondering why some object changes when theu claim they did not touch it...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, I think you are probably right. Strange thing is even when the error happened, if I print the dict to console, I can see the entries there. When I modify code according to the answer, error disappears and I get the value correctly and it's never `None`. I'd imagine the value to be `None` or empty if the dictionary didn't have the key. I'm very new to python, so I honestly have no clue. But thanks you guys for your help and ideas.